# Speed up the 'for' loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

Combined has 6713 rows and bids has 7656334 rows:

```
i = 1
for(i in 1:length(combined$bidder_id)){
  combined$no_of_bids[i] = count(bids[bids$bidder_id == combined$bidder_id[i],])
  i = i + 1
}
```

It takes about 30 mins to run this code. Any suggestion to speed it up?

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Read about `merge` and search for posts about `group by count`. No need for `forloop`, learn how to do things in R way.

Answer (score 0):

In this case loop is slower then other R functions

For example, in `tidyverse` style `group_by()` does the job much faster

```
library(tidyverse)

bids <- tibble(bidder_id=sample(1:1000, 100000, replace = TRUE))

combined <- bids %>% 
  group_by(bidder_id) %>% 
  summarise(no_of_bids = n())
```

Comment: We can use [count](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html): `bids %>% count(bidder_id)`

Comment: of course we can. 
Your code shorter. But we don't know what next Bala want to do with this data

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(combined,
          count(bids, bidder_id),
          by = 'bidder_id')
```

Next question please post a reproducible example.